# Adjusting a Customer's AppExchange Subscription

Tags: appexchange, lma, cma, stripe

We offer a monthly and annual subscription to our AppExchange package, and we use LMA and CMA along with Stripe to manage and see all the subscribers and their payments.

A situation came up where a customer mistakenly bought a number of seats on the monthly subscription, but actually wants to do the annual subscription.  We already have their transaction for the first monthly subscription, and all that subscription/transaction/license detail has already shown up as records in LMA and CMA.

Question - *What's the best way to have "upgrade" to the annual plan considering they already paid for one month's worth?*

#### Potential Solution...?

At the very bottom of [this doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/cma_key_objects.htm), they mention:

> To update subscription plan, subscription, invoice, invoice item, or transaction data, use the Stripe dashboard or API.

If I make these adjustments in Stripe, how will they be imported/synced to CMA?  Will they create a new set of Transactions and Subscription records, or somehow auto-adjust the existing ones?

I can see things getting messy trying to manually adjust/delete records on the CMA / LMA side of things, and would love to hear how others have handled this situation.